# PKI user certificate credential roaming works on Windows 7, but not on XP SP3

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, pki, credentials, roaming

We have implemented credential roaming for user certificates on our domain.  Everything is set up per Technet in Certification Authority and Group Policy.  User certificates are roaming correctly, but only on Windows 7 workstations.  For some reason, our XP workstations (all are SP3), are not picking up the user certs from AD.  I've verified that [KB907247](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907247) is in fact included as part of SP3.

Can anyone provide some help on this issue?

Comment: this concept seems very interesting... check out some steps listed on [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/06/certs-on-wheels-understanding-credential-roaming.aspx), as it explains the steps that are taken by the system.  Did you verify the DLLs listed in that article (dimsntfy.dll, dimsroam.dll ) are of the same version as listed in KB907247 (likely yes since you have SP3 clients)?

Comment: Can you list the mode your domain controllers are operating in, and what OS you are using?

Comment: The domain controllers are 2008 R2 running in functional level 2003 (we had just upgraded our last two 2003 DCs last week and are planning on moving to functional level 2008 R2 in a few weeks).